# Suddenly I have started getting 404 wordpress errors

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, 404

Suddenly I have started getting 404 error on Google Webmaster.

The backend is wordpress.

404 link is http://digitalanalog.in/2011/07/05/augmented-reality-interior-designer-kinect-hack/1345295070000/1345781600000
and it is pointing from this page http://digitalanalog.in/2011/07/05/augmented-reality-interior-designer-kinect-hack/1345295070000/
(this url has been automatically generated. Have no clue how this url exist)

I am getting 404 errors of the similar pattern on all the pages

Comment: Have you checked your logs for the referrer for traffic on these links or tried running a site crawler like [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) to determine whether a plugin on your site is generating bad links? (Possibly related: your sitemap is broken)

Answer (score 2):

the answer is most-likely your use of the Disqus commenting system, where Google is trying to find URLs in JavaScript.

However, Disqus is blaming Google for the issue:

> We believe these 404 crawl errors are due to search engines like Google trying to crawl dynamic JavaScript-assembled links coded in the Disqus WordPress plugin. We've recommended reaching out to Google directly about this, as enough feedback may help them resolve this.

There's more discussion on this at the [Google Webmaster Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/zvez-eib0Ao/discussion).

Comment: Good to know, thanks! @rikki - what does the user see when they reach a 404? A generic "page not found" or have you put in some code to direct them to possibly related pages _ala_ "did you mean..."? Also, are these proper 404's sent with the proper 404 header instead of a 200 and then content is shown telling the user no content was found?